# dismissViewControllerAnimated causing black screen ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

So in my app, i am getting blank screens between the view controllers navigation. I figured that dismissViewControllerAnimated was the culprit. So at one place i changed this below code -

```
[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^() {
        BCDThankYouViewController  *thankuView=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThankyouView"];
        [[self topViewController ]presentViewController:thankuView animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
```

With this below code -

```
[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
BCDThankYouViewController  *thankuView=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThankyouView"];
            [[self topViewController ]presentViewController:thankuView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Where vc is -

```
 UIViewController *vc = self.presentingViewController;
    while (vc.presentingViewController) {
        vc = vc.presentingViewController;

    }
```

And it worked. But in some other part of my app i have code like this below -

```
[weakPresentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:_animateClosingModal completion:^{
            [weakSelf handleDelayedLoginActions:userInfo withPortfolio:portfolio];
        }];
```

I changed it with -

```
[weakPresentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:_animateClosingModal completion:nil];
            [weakSelf handleDelayedLoginActions:userInfo withPortfolio:portfolio];
```

But still i see a blank screen before my next page loads. In this above piece of code weakPresentingViewController is

```
id __weak weakSelf = self;
    UIViewController * __weak weakPresentingViewController = (UIViewController *)_loginManagerDelegate;
```

Please let me know what is wrong here? Why am i getting black screen before page loads?

Answer (score 0):

First presenting view controller need time to do it.

Once you put the code in the dismiss block, that means after dismiss animation is over, then the presenting begins, and as we know, presenting needs time, so there is a very short time the key window has no view controller, surely you will see a black screen.

When you put the code out of the dismiss block, the code will be called one by one, but the dismiss has a animation which last for a very short time, so when the dismiss is animating, the code for presenting view controller is execused, so after a very short time of the dismiss animation, we now can see the screen behind the dismissed view controller, then ,the presenting is done, so you can not see a black screen.

But I have to say , even we will not get the black screen, it's not means the code is good.

In my opinion , it is much better to make a better workflow for the app, such as present,dismiss, push ,pop and so on, to avoid empty root view controller of the key window.